# Как сверстать облако текста со скошенными уголками?

Tags: css

Как легче всего сверстать такой блок?

[image]

Comment: Цельная заливка + after и before с абсолютным позицированием и [правильным заданием рамки](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/). Совместимсоть, насколько понимаю, 2.1+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, через blockquote это будет правильней всего.

3 бекграунда через запятую в css-е.

Верх не повторять, середина повторять вниз, и низ со скошенным углом и выпирающим элементом.

Comment: @eprivalov1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Crus Как мне сделать срезанный угол и треугольник?

Comment: Картинкой прижатой к низу. Всю линию. Начиная слева от среза и до края права.

Comment: @Crus А возможно ли справиться без картинок?

Comment: http://pcvector.net/scripts/layout_and_interface/242-skoshennye-elementy-na-css3.html

Можете поколдовать с псевдо-элементами и тенями. Но, решение может оказаться совершенно НЕ кросброузерным.

То что я указал с картинками тоже от ie10+. Но, пожалуй, за это решение я был бы спокойней всего.